# application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions not getting called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, appdelegate

I'm trying to figure why it doesn't seem "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" is being called when my app is starting up. My NSLog (@"Launch!") statement isn't showing up in the console, and the dictionary after it isn't being created either. If it makes a difference I'm using Storyboarding with a Navigation controller as the initial view. I tried adding a "object" to the Navigation controller and set it to "AppDelegate" and then setting it as the referencing outlet, but that didn't seem to make a difference either. Isn't this method supposed to be called every time the app launches? I even reset the simulator, but still nothing.

Thanks.

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  PersonLibraryiOS
//
//  Created by Joey on 11/7/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Joey. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "AddViewController.h"
#import "Person.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize PersonDict;

-(void)addtoDict:(Person *)newPerson
{
    [PersonDict setObject:@"newPerson" forKey:[newPerson name]];
}



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSLog (@"Launch!");

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
    PersonDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"diskDict"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Must've been having a bad day when I wrote this originally. Removed the extremely unnecessary attitude from this post and clarified some things.**

If you didn't know, `return` returns control to the caller of a method/subroutine. Since you return YES from the method before you create the dictionary, it never gets created and set to the property.

Additionally, the syntax for whatever you're trying to assign that `NSMutableDictionary` to is incorrect. It seems personDict is a property based on the `@synthesize` so:

You're accessing the instance variable backing it. You're supposed to access properties using dot notation like this:

```
self.personDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"diskDict"];

//in addToDict
[self.personDict setObject:@"newPerson" forKey:[newPerson name]];
```

or using the setters and getters (dot notation has the identical effect):

```
[self personDict];
[self setPersonDict];
```

I don't think your usage of `setObject:forKey:` is what you intended.

```
//the object associated with the key will always be
//the NSString "newPerson" 
[self.personDict setObject:@"newPerson" forKey:[newPerson name]];
//did you mean to set the object to the method argument newPerson?
[self.personDict setObject: newPerson forKey:[newPerson name]];
```

Also, in Objective-C, you should name properties and variables in camel case, with the first letter being lower case. Like `myCoolVar`, or in this case, `personDict` rather than `PersonDict`; first letter capital camel case is used for class names, like your `Person` class.

Finally, if you manually `@synthesize`, it's a good idea to name the backing variable `_<variable name>` to avoid accessing it by accident.

```
@synthesize personDict = _personDict;
```

Comment: What can I say, I'm new and trying the best I can to learn. The problem turned out to be due to the "return YES" statement being above everything else. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if you feel like I'm harping on you, I'm not; I'm new myself. I think the best way to learn Objective-C is to get a good book; jumping right in and adapting tends to lead to misunderstanding of fundamental concepts. I speak from experience on that one.

Comment: I've been at this for a few months (and I've been using books too) but sometimes when trying to figure out more complicated concepts I tend to gloss over the basics. Thanks for the edits BTW. I see where I had that wrong as well.

Comment: I've been at this for a few months as well. At first I was having trouble, but then I picked up a copy of *Programming iOS 5*. It instructed me to read the first half or so of K&R's *The C Programming Language*. Some say you should start with Objective-C, but I found that learning the basics of subroutines, data types, control flow, pointers, etc, by learning C first helped me a lot. It didn't take long before I could do the exercises. Then, I could focus on learning stuff specific to Object Oriented Programming. PiOS5 tends to be on the long winded side, but it's worked for me so far. :)